# General error Telecom doesn't have a default value with function in model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to achieve by sorting it if it is a different telecom, but it doesn't work. Thank you in Advance. Anyways this is my code.

If you have any questions please ask me based on that I can share more details.

**Controller:**

```
$contact->telecom = getPhoneType();
```

**Model:**

```
 public function getPhoneType() {

        $s = substr($this->mobile, 0, 5);
        if ($s == "63905") {
            return "Globe";
        }

        if ($s == "63907") {
            return "Smart";
        }

        if ($s == "63922") {
            return "Sun Cellular";
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `model` because it is returning value in three cases:

**Solution 1:**

```
//return some default value if none of the if condition works:
public function getPhoneType() {

        $s = substr($this->mobile, 0, 5);
        if ($s == "63905") {
            return "Globe";
        }

        if ($s == "63907") {
            return "Smart";
        }

        if ($s == "63922") {
            return "Sun Cellular";
        }

        return "Some default value";
  }
```

**Solution 2:**

Handle this on `controller` side:

```
$phone_type = getPhoneType();
$contact->telecom = isset($phone_type) ? $phone_type : "default value" ;
```

**Solution 3:**

Presently you might be having your column like this:
[image: telecom structure]

Click on Change and then set some default value

[image: setting default value]

Try one of the above solution!! It should work.

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'telecom' doesn't have a default value

Comment: Try setting a default value or Null in database for telecom column

Comment: oay will try it